# Php how to echo if

Tags: php

Hello I have problem with `PHP` `if else` at `echo` part 
where my `echo` didn't count my `php` result with * instead its calculate normally with variable `$tot_gaji`

```
<td align="right">
  <?php 
    $tot_gaji = $row['gajipokok']+$rows['jlhbonus'];
    if ($tot_gaji>=4500000) {
        $tot_gaji+0.05*$tot_gaji;
    } elseif ($tot_gaji>=5000000) {
        $tot_gaji+0.15*$tot_gaji;
    }                   

    echo number_format($tot_gaji,0,".",","); 
  ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you want to store the results from the lines `$tot_gaji+0.05*$tot_gaji;` as at the moment you don't do anything with the value calculated.

Comment: ummm the calculation is if 4500000 then the echo calucation will be `$tot_gaji+0.05*$tot_gaji;` but if 5000000 then the echo will appear `$tot_gaji+0.15*$tot_gaji;` something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't assign the calculated results to the variable, it be still unchanged. So you have to assign the calculated result to a variable

```
<td align="right">
    <?php 
    $tot_gaji = $row['gajipokok']+$rows['jlhbonus'];
    if ($tot_gaji>=4500000) {
        $tot_gaji = $tot_gaji+0.05*$tot_gaji;
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^
    } elseif ($tot_gaji>=5000000) {
        $tot_gaji = $tot_gaji+0.15*$tot_gaji;
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    echo number_format($tot_gaji,0,".",","); 
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new with this stuff what kind of **assign the calculated result should I put there?**

Comment: `$tot_gaji + 0.05 * $tot_gaji` should be assigned to `$tot_gaji`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the mathematics expression to any variable that's why the values of variable `$tot_gai` stay original

```
$tot_gaji = $row['gajipokok']+$rows['jlhbonus'];
if ($tot_gaji>=4500000) 
{
  $final = $tot_gaji+0.05*$tot_gaji;
}
elseif ($tot_gaji>=5000000)
{
  $final = $tot_gaji+0.15*$tot_gaji;
}  
echo number_format($final,0,".",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the calculated values to `$tot_gaji`

```
$tot_gaji = $row['gajipokok']+$rows['jlhbonus'];

if ($tot_gaji >= 4500000) {

    $tot_gaji = $tot_gaji+0.05*$tot_gaji;
} elseif ($tot_gaji>=5000000) {

    $tot_gaji = $tot_gaji+0.15*$tot_gaji;
}                   

echo number_format($tot_gaji,0,".",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than not assigning your adjusted figure your second condition may not be met.  i.e. a number such as 6000000 is greater than 4500000, it is also greater than 5000000, under your logic the first condition is met.

You likely want to switch your conditions or test for a range.

```
<?php


function adjustment($num)
{
    if($num > 10) {
        $num += 0.25 * $num;
    } else if ($num > 5) {
        $num += 0.5 * $num;
    }

    return $num;
}

foreach([1,6,12] as $num) {
    echo adjustment($num), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
9
15
```